# Any chance for fully working X1600 PCI-E ID 71c3/Unity under Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ati, radeon, pcie

How can I get Unity working under an ATI Radeon X1600 PCI-E on Ubuntu 12.04? I'm rather Windows guy, but I can do some things with CLI.

ATI seems to have ended support for this card for both Windows and Linux. Theres no proper driver in jockey; binary driver from Software Center doesn't give Unity, just Unity 2D.

Yes, I've tried the commands from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153474/Ubuntu-12-04-resolution-issue-ati-radeon-x1600) - without any positive results; should I try installing drivers manually?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you mean by "fully working"? What is the actual problem? "get it to work" does not describe the problem you have with the graphics card. Have you tried the commands from this post? http://askubuntu.com/questions/153474/ubuntu-12-04-resolution-issue-ati-radeon-x1600?rq=1 -- did you try with unity 2d instead of unity?

Comment: I mean, i want full support for Unity/3D and for what i readed so far, ATI ended support for this card for both Windows and Linux.
Theres no proper driver in jockey; binary driver from Software Centre doesnt give Unity, just Unity 2D.
Yes, ive tried the commands from mentioned post - without any positive results; should i try installing drivers manually?

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A  http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get this card running is to do nothing; Ubuntu ships with fully functional drivers for this (and virtually all AMD) card(s).

Some people with newer cards may want to install the AMD proprietary `fglrx` drivers; they offer somewhat improved OpenGL performance and features, as well as better power management, but sometimes have annoying bugs. Sometimes they have support for newer cards than the default Ubuntu drivers, too.

As you've found out, AMD has dropped support for your card in `fglrx`, so that option is not available to you. To make matters worse, installing `fglrx` will disable the default drivers, so trying to do so won't improve things ☺.

Uninstall `fglrx` and you'll get 3D working again.